# How to shuffle list in lisp?

Tags: common-lisp, elisp

It's very simple program which just return the input as a list shuffled. I wrote this program in python. Now I want to convert this program to lisp code. but I couldn't. How do I write down this program in lisp?

```
def my_shuffle(a, b, c, d):
    return [b, c, d, a]
```

I tried the following code but an error occur.

```
(defun my_shuffle (a b c d) (list b c d a))
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. `(my_shuffle 1 2 3 4)` returns `(2 3 4 1)`. How are you calling it?

Comment: n.b. Saying that there was "an error" is rarely useful unless you say what the error was.  Always include the exact error message, and how you triggered it.

Comment: @phils: I call it by `(my_shuffle (list 1 2 3 4))`. It seems I'm passing incorrect argument. As you say `(my_shuffle 1 2 3 4)` returns `(2 3 4 1)` and this is what I want.

Comment: You better call a function with four parameters then with four arguments, not only one list.

Comment: Calling `my_shuffle([1,2,3,4])` in Python doesn't work either. None of them takes one list parameter, but both takes 4 arguments and return a list with those in a different order than called.

Answer (score 10):

Thee are several things here that I think that need to be pointing out. First the code that you presented is correct but do shuffle a list, present a new list of four algorithms that you pass, allways with the same order. First of all shuffle a sequence is:

> generating a random permutation of a finite sequence

From wikipedia you can find several algorithms for that:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Also in the [rosseta code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Knuth_shuffle#Common_Lisp) there is an implementation of the knuth shuffle:

```
(defun nshuffle (sequence)
  (loop for i from (length sequence) downto 2
        do (rotatef (elt sequence (random i))
                    (elt sequence (1- i))))
  sequence)
```

Then if you apply this in the repl:

```
CL-USER> (nshuffle (list 1 2 3 4))
(3 1 4 2)
CL-USER> (nshuffle (list 1 2 3 4))
(3 1 2 4)
```

Note Two different results on the same list!!! (also the same can happen, because is a random order)

In python there are build algorithms for that:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle

also in  the Common lisp library Alexandria:

```
CL-USER> (ql:quickload :alexandria)
To load "alexandria":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    alexandria
; Loading "alexandria"

(:ALEXANDRIA)
CL-USER> (alexandria:shuffle (list 1 2 3 4))
(3 2 4 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(defun my_shuffle (a b c d) (list b c d a))
```

The above code defines a function which will take **4 items** and return a rearranged list of those 4 items. It can take input of 4 lists, 4 atoms, 4 numbers, 4 anything, but it cannot separate sublists present inside a single list.

What you can do is:

```
(defun my_shuffle (myList) 
(list (second myList) (third myList) (fourth myList) (first myList)))
```

or

```
(defun my_shuffle (myList)
(list (cadr myList) (caddr myList) (cadddr myList) (car myList)))
```

or

```
(defun my_shuffle (myList)
(list (nth 1 myList) (nth 2 myList) (nth 3 myList) (nth 1 myList)))
```

---

`car` returns the first element of a list
`cdr` returns the tail of a list (part of the list following `car` of the list)
I have used combinations of car and cdr to extract the different elements of the list. Find that in your textbook.

`first`, `second`, `third`, `fourth` are relatively easy to use and do the same thing as `car`, `cadr`, `caddr` and  `cadddr`

`(nth x list)` returns the (x+1)th item of the list, counting from zero.
So,
(nth 3 (list a b c d)) => d
(nth 0 (list a b c d)) => a
and so on.

Comment: I would suggest that `nth` is particularly worth pointing out here.

Comment: thx for mentioning it sir, I forgot about it so easily. I added it